# How can I control wifi user's bandwidth connected to Huawei HG8245T modem?

Tags: router, modem

How can I control wifi user's bandwidth connected to Huawei HG8245 modem/router?
I searched about QoS, Type-Limit, etc.. but this huawei router model has limited features. Can anyone advise? Thanks.